# How to get multiple user images from Twitter (OAuth)?

Tags: coldfusion, oauth, twitter, railo

I have a log in to my site using Twitter. It all works great.

Whilst I can do a call to get the current users details etc and log them in, I'm a bit stumped on how I make calls to get the profile images of users stored in my database; those who may not be using the website at that time?

I am using the monkehTweets Twitter library:
https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/monkehTweets

To get the current user, I sign them in and do this:

```
application.objMonkehTweet.setFinalAccessDetails(

oauthToken          = returnData.token,
oauthTokenSecret    = returnData.token_secret,
userAccountName     = returnData.screen_name

);

local.userDetails = application.objMonkehTweet.getUserDetails(user_id=returnData.user_id);
```

As part of the log in process on my website, if a user hasn't used the site before, I store their Twitter ID.

I was hoping to then use this to display their profile images on the posts they make to other users.

What is the best approach to achieve this? With the Facebook API, you can make requests to a URL with the ID...but Twitter doesn't seem to allow this.

I would prefer not to 'store' the image on my own file system. This was a possibility I had in mind, but I'd rather use the API to always ensure the latest data.

Is there a way to use my own app details through OAuth to access this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael.

PS - I am using ColdFusion (Railo) to do my server-side based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The twitter api returns profiles with the images (if you are looking it up) in the key profile_image_url

So you could store them in a cache like:

```
if(!cacheKeyExists(twitterID)){
    // Code to get a twitter profile through monkehtweet
  cachePut(twitterID, profile.profile_image_url);
}
return cacheGet(twitterID);
```

Hope  this helps